# Android + Facebook SDK 3.6.0 + HelloFacebookSample

Tags: android, facebook

I've been trying to run the HelloFacebookSample in several physical devices but when I press the Login button I obtain this message:

> 01-10 16:49:08.606: W/ContextImpl(26302): Implicit intents with
>   startService are not safe: Intent {
>   act=com.facebook.platform.PLATFORM_SERVICE
>   cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] }
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:517
>   com.facebook.GetTokenClient.start:62
>   com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$GetTokenAuthHandler.tryAuthorize:535 
>   01-10 16:49:08.696: E/JavaBinder(26302): **!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION
>   !!!**

have I installed something wrong? I've not modified any code at all. Has anybody run this example successfully? Any comment will be appreciated :)

Comment: In previous versions of facebook sdk there is no necessity of same keystore for facebook appid. But for current version the keystore file is same as you generated appid from facebook developer account.